# Spark: Dataframe action really slow when upgraded from 2.1.0 to 2.2.1

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I just upgraded spark 2.1.0 to spark 2.2.1. Has anyone seen extreme slow behavior on `dataframe.filter(…).collect()`?.. specifically a `collect` operation with `filter` before. `dataframe.collect` seems to run okay. However, `dataframe.filter(…).collect()` takes forever. it contains only 2 records. and its on a unit test. When I go back to spark 2.1.0, its back to normal speed

I have looked at the thread dump and could not find an obvious cause. I have made an effort to make sure all the libraries I am using are also using Spark 2.2.1. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

It seems to be stuck at this stacktrace

```
scala.collection.mutable.FlatHashTable$class.addEntry(FlatHashTable.scala:151)
scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.addEntry(HashSet.scala:40)
scala.collection.mutable.FlatHashTable$class.addElem(FlatHashTable.scala:142)
scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.addElem(HashSet.scala:40)
scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.$plus$eq(HashSet.scala:59)
scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.$plus$eq(HashSet.scala:40)
scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Growable.scala:59)
scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Growable.scala:59)
scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
scala.collection.mutable.AbstractSet.$plus$plus$eq(Set.scala:46)
scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.clone(HashSet.scala:83)
scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.clone(HashSet.scala:40)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExpressionSet.$plus(ExpressionSet.scala:65)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExpressionSet.$plus(ExpressionSet.scala:50)
scala.collection.SetLike$$anonfun$$plus$plus$1.apply(SetLike.scala:141)
scala.collection.SetLike$$anonfun$$plus$plus$1.apply(SetLike.scala:141)
scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1.foreach(HashSet.scala:316)
scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:972)
scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:972)
scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:972)
scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:972)
scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.foldLeft(Traversable.scala:104)
scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.$div$colon(TraversableOnce.scala:151)
scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.$div$colon(Traversable.scala:104)
scala.collection.SetLike$class.$plus$plus(SetLike.scala:141)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExpressionSet.$plus$plus(ExpressionSet.scala:50)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.UnaryNode$$anonfun$getAliasedConstraints$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:323)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.UnaryNode$$anonfun$getAliasedConstraints$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:320)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.UnaryNode.getAliasedConstraints(LogicalPlan.scala:320)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project.validConstraints(basicLogicalOperators.scala:65)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.constraints$lzycompute(QueryPlan.scala:188) => holding Monitor(org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Aggregate@1129881457})
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.constraints(QueryPlan.scala:188)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Aggregate.validConstraints(basicLogicalOperators.scala:555)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.constraints$lzycompute(QueryPlan.scala:188) => holding Monitor(org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Aggregate@1129881457})
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.constraints(QueryPlan.scala:188)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.getConstraints(QueryPlan.scala:196)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PruneFilters$$anonfun$apply$16$$anonfun$25.apply(Optimizer.scala:717)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PruneFilters$$anonfun$apply$16$$anonfun$25.apply(Optimizer.scala:716)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$partition$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:314)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$partition$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:314)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.partition(TraversableLike.scala:314)
scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.partition(Traversable.scala:104)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PruneFilters$$anonfun$apply$16.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:716)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PruneFilters$$anonfun$apply$16.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:705)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:256)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PruneFilters.apply(Optimizer.scala:705)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.PruneFilters.apply(Optimizer.scala:704)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:74)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:78) => holding Monitor(org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution@1193326176})
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:78)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84) => holding Monitor(org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution@1193326176})
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:80)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:89) => holding Monitor(org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution@1193326176})
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:89)
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2837)
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2387)
```

Comment: need more details. it was very generic question. have you checked spark ui like stages etc...?

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram yeah spark ui shows that there are no "ACTIVE" jobs running. In other words, number of "COMPLETED" jobs it shows is 28 and it stays that way for the rest of the time. So 
I pause the execution of my test using IntelliJ to check what line of code its running or stuck at. Everytime I pause it, it shows to be executing some lines of code in scala.collection package. To be exact, `sameElements` is the function that it gets paused at a lot..

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. So the problem was regarding this property `spark.sql.constraintPropagation.enabled`. The default value is `true` in Spark 2.2.1. The stacktrace indicates that its stuck in some query plan generation. I found my answer in [this blog](https://medium.com/@viirya/slowness-of-ml-pipeline-in-spark-6ec76d66042f)

Short answer: Set the said property to false. `spark.conf.set(SQLConf.CONSTRAINT_PROPAGATION_ENABLED.key, false)`